# run jquery code after new elements load

Tags: jquery

I have link with `id="#knav1"`. After click in div with `id="navldesc"` load select element with `class="selnav1"`.

```
$("#knav1").click(function(){
$("#navldesc").load('/const/api.php?nvsload=y&komplektn=kompl1');
});
```

But next script not working:

```
$(".selnav1").change(function(){
alert('ewfew');
});
```

How to i fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for dynamically loaded element's like this

```
$(document).on('change','.selnav1',function(){
  alert('ewfew');
});
```

Comment: @user125697 when i click to toogle i see "You can accept an answer in 10 minute"